# Tutorial for Topdown 3D

Tags: c++, 3d, topdown

Well, i'm looking for a good guide to program Topdown 3D in C++. Where i can find a good one?

Thanks.

Comment: Well it's more of a combination of things: first learn C++, then learn graphics programming (2D then 3D), then learn game programming, then make a top-down game. How far along are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topdown isn't any different than any other 3D programming - except for the position of the viewer.

You can get some more information about what you want to do by checking out gluLookAt()

Your "up" would be X or Z depending on what you wanted to do and if you still wanted to use right-handed coordinates for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Isometric](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/downloads/download.asp?letter=I) at the nehe tutorials site.